# How to Refresh watermarked images on magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, watermark

I have removed the watermark from the admin section but the images are not being refresh as normal?

IS it perhaps a permissions error?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing all caches, including magento image cache.

If that doesn't work, try re-indexing.